# How was the agent of the other research facility saved?

Tags: elfen-lied

Elfen Lied's manga's ending has many ambiguous points, but at least it is possible to make up a satisfying explanation for most of them. One I couldn't make anything up for, however, was this:

There is an agent spy from a different research facility whose name I forgot. He helped the assistant escape during the Diclonius outbreak in the manga by holding the elevator brakes.

He was cornered, and it is suggested that he was killed. Until the end of the manga, of course, where apparently he survives and has no idea how.

I have no idea what saved him. What was it?

For a moment I considered that an earthquake just made a bigger hole that killed the opponents, but as far as I can remember, there were no more earthquakes at that specific moment.

Comment: The agent spy was a woman, and her name was not revealed in the story.

Comment: @yibe: Now that's a disturbing turn of events... XD

Comment: @Mochan: Hm? Why do you say that?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, wrong question. Very sorry DX

Answer (score 3):

That's a good question, I like it. 
Spoilers up to the last chapter of the manga below.

Here is what the Agent says in the last chapter:

> [image][image]

I suppose what really saved her was

> the Vector Attack Craft, the same one that save Arakawa on the shore. The Vector Attack Craft was developed in Saseba - a research project of the government, basically ruled by the same people that were the Agent's bosses. So the guys in the Vector Attack Craft had some kind of motivation to save the Agent.